# Screen Scraping of Image Links in PHP

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I have a website that contains many different pages of products and each page has a certain amount of images in the same format across all pages. I want to be able to screen scrap each page's url so I can retrieve the url of each image from each page. The idea is to make a gallery for each page made up of hotlinked images.

I know this can be done in php, but I am not sure how to scrap the page for multiple links. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using a DOM parser, such as PHP's very own [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Example:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://example.com/images.php');
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src') . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I tried this but get this error about 15 times down the page:

Notice: Undefined property: DOMElement::$src in C:\Users\User\Desktop\PortableWebAp4.0\PortableWebAp4.0.pro\Program\www\localhost\test.php on line 12

Do I need to include the DomDocument or anything? Sorry I am new to PHP.

Comment: @Jeremy - Initially, my code had a mistake in it, which I've since corrected. I changed `$image->src` to `$image->getAttribute('src')`, which is the correct way to get an attribute. I should have commented when I corrected it, sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks so much it works perfectly! I was looking at some other code today that was 5x longer than that and this works brilliantly! Cheers!

Comment: hello there. I got this error when I tried the one above...

  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Attribute class redefined in Entity,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression (regex) to go through the page source and parse all the IMG tags.

This regex will do the job quite nicely: `<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"`

How does this work?

```
// <img[^>]+src="(.*?)"
// 
// Match the characters "<img" literally «<img»
// Match any character that is not a ">" «[^>]+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Match the characters "src="" literally «src="»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
// Match the character """ literally «"»
```

Sample PHP code:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    // image URL is in $result[0][$i];
}
```

You'll have to do a bit more work to resolve things like relative URLs.

Comment: What if the src is surrounded with single quotes, for instance? Due to the possibility of inconsistencies that would be a pain to account for, generally, using an XML parser is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, do I need to use a regex if I know that there is only one possible way the image is being displayed?

e.g all images follow the format:

<div title="" largeUrl="http://a.com/image.jpg">

Comment: Although it's fast, this way lies madness. HTML is just too unpredictable. Use PHP's DomDocument (and possibly XPath).

Answer (score 0):

I really like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for things like this. An example of grabbing images is right there on the front page:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you this to scrap pages.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

but it requires PHP 5+.