# Remove <img> tag when src contains the word adult

Tags: php

How can I remove entire `<img width= height= alt= src=*** >` where src contains the word adult ?
This is a part of website.
Thanks!

this is the part of my code that gets me the `<img>`

```
$dom->load ('domain');
    $CONTENTS = $post->getElementsByTagName( "description" );
    $content = $CONTENTS->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $nohtml = strip_tags($content,'<br><b><img>');
```

Comment: what about some source of the part where the <img> tag is being generated?

Comment: can we see the code generating the `<img...` tag? or else, would this be more easily done with javascript?

Comment: Javascript + DOM can perform it easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scrape all images with DOMDocument [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261820/screen-scraping-of-image-links-in-php/3261848#3261848), then check their sources for stopwords and if a match occur, remove them from the tree.

*Update*

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    if(substr_count($image->getAttribute('src'), 'adult')) {
        $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mikey all you need to do is `$doc->loadHTML($nohtml)` then there you go, you got all of your images, then check their `src` attrib against your stopwords.

Comment: Thanks for the info but how can I check it?

Comment: Please note that if <img> tag lies deeper and isn't a direct child of root then doing `$doc->removeChild($image)` will issue a `DOMEception`. Do `$image->parentNode->removeChild($image)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$('img[src|="adult"]').hide()
```

Comment: Isn't there a jQuery selector implementation for PHP ;)

Comment: I know, but it is so simple in JQ.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$dom->loadHTML($nohtml);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ( preg_match('/(list|of|bad|words)/i', $image->getAttribute('src')) ) {
        $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
    }
}
```