# Facebook-like image scraping

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to implement an image scraper feature that works similar to the way Facebook does when you post a link. I don't care about the actual UI part. I just want to pass a URL to a script and have it return the URLs of all the images on the page.

It's really easy to put together something that only works *some* of the time - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261820/screen-scraping-of-image-links-in-php), for example - but I want something that works reasonably well.

I'm capable of writing this kind of thing myself, but it of course would be dumb for me to do that if there's already something written that's available for free.

Does anyone know of such a tool that exists? I don't care what language it uses as long as it will run on *nix.

Comment: I did similar scrapper with python (PyQt4) and JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can start with python and Scrapy http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html