# How to get images from url to JSON

Tags: php, regex, json

I am trying to get all the images from a url (www.xxxxx.co.uk/bar.html) and put them to JSON

like

```
{"images":http://www.xxxxx.co.uk/foo.jpg}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents('www.xxxxx.co.uk/bar.html'); 

function linkExtractor($html){ 
$linkArray = array(); 
if(preg_match_all('/<img\s+.*?src=[\"\']?([^\"\' >]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>/i',$html,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER)){ 
foreach($matches as $match){ 
$arr = array('images' => $match); 
} 
} 
echo json_encode($arr); 
} 

echo json_encode($arr); 
?>
```

**Edit:**

So I tried this:

```
$page = file_get_contents('www.xxxxx.co.uk/bar.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
foreach($images as $image) {
    $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
    $arr = array('images' => $src );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

and I am getting these errors:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3188 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3207 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3226 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3245 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : iframe in Entity, line: 3287 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : iframe in Entity, line: 3330 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3351 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3370 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3389 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3389 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3408 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 3408 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3427 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3446 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3466 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3485 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5
{"images":"loader.gif"}{"images":"logo.png"}{"images":"facebook.png"}{"images":"Yotube.png"}{"images":"twitter.png"}{"images":"Soundcloud.png"}{"images":"1355334348_br_down.png"}{"images":"video images\/ONYX sofa.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/aaron duran.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/littledragon.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/cantalivering house.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Chef.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/monument valley.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/set a drift t shirts.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Leica camera.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Bubbledogs restuarant.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Architectural density.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Seven Automatic Landscapes.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/alphabet.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/offices in the forest.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Environmental Street Art by ROA.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/ Camille Seaman.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Klaus Pitchler.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Lowdi.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Mary OMalley.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Patricia Piccinini.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Santa Cruz.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Sonia Rentsch.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Studio Natural.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/The Tea Calender.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Watch Dogs.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/wes21.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Act Romegialli Architects.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Romain Jacquet-Lagreze.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Nicholas Hance McElroy.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Insa.gif"}{"images":"video images\/Tsatsas bag.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/st pancras.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/anthillfilms.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/mt wolf.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/die.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/jazz that nobody asked for.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/oscilate.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/ghostpoet.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/oak hanger.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/iceball.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/fabian oefner.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/yago portal.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/illustrations on bike wheels.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/symmetrees.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/undercity.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/IFHY.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/the abc of architects.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/chum.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/crankworx.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/romare.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/White noise.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/silvestre architects.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/airport.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/feather.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Nico Van Der Meulen.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/51m trampoline.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/lets talk about soil.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/alberto seveso.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/ibike.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/robs wood grain bike.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/smokehouse.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/laurent chehere.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/SOHN.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/the employment.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/little printer.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/procrastination.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/touchwood commercial.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/fusefones.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/allandale house.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/Spherikal.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/power.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/reykjavik house.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/click&grow.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/sfelt table.jpg"}{"images":"video images\/gopro.jpg"}
```

1. Why do the links have / not just /?
2. Why is it doing multiple "{"images":"video images/gopro.jpg"}"
3. What is the `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3107 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 5` error about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen Scraping of Image Links in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261820/screen-scraping-of-image-links-in-php)

Comment: Is there any error message or is it just not working ? We need some more information !

Comment: @Maximilian +1 I got your back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it right, there were a few things missing like `http://` in front of your URL and returning a value from your function instead of echoing it.
try this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.setours.com');

function linkExtractor($html){
    $imageArr = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($images as $image) {
        array_push($imageArr, $image->getAttribute('src'));
    }
    return $imageArr;
}

echo json_encode(array("images" => linkExtractor($html)));
```

Use the @ infront of the `loadHTML` function to supress the warnings of unknown HTML elements.

Comment: this doesnt do "image": the links ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) parser to extract information from HTML documents:

```
function extractImgages($url) {

    // Prepare result
    $result = array('images' => array());

    // Create a document object out of the HTML
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    if(!@$doc->loadHTML($url)) {
        throw new Exception('Bad HTML');
    }

    // Iterate through '<img>' elements and store urls
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
        $result['images'][]= $img->getAttribute('src');
    }

    return json_encode($result);
}
```

I use the silence operator `@` when parsing the HTML because when HTML comes from untrusted sources it can produce warnings if the HTML source is not valid. The `@` suppresses them.

Comment: I got this `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Bad HTML' in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 8`

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be `@$doc->loadHTMLFile()`

Comment: Now I am getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_econde() in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/json.php on line 20`

Comment: Man! this is a typo. Please read the text of the error message before drop it here. sorry